# How RSS readers treats output from .php file

Tags: php, xml, rss, rss-reader

I am dynamically generating rss ouput from a php file and the url to output the feed is **http://mysite/rss-feed.php**. I have followed this [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-phprss/index.html) to generate the feed.

I have seen some of the rss output url, They wont be having any file extension. I am not using any MVC framework, so the url will have file extension also

As per my website is hosted in yahoo small business, I have no access to mod_rewrite and .htaccess file to hide the extension of .php

Even though I have set **header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=ISO-8859-1")**. I have doubt that all rss readers will consider my rss output and I have tested the rss ouput using W3C RSS validator tool, it says its valid RSS.

I have also got 2 questions

**1)** Is this the right way to tell readers to read the rss from php file insted of xml file.

**2)** Which is the better way to keep the url, **http://mysite/rss-feed.php** or **http://mysite/rss-feed**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, the reader should care about the MIME type, not its extension.
2. It doesn't matter, but I'd prefer the latter because it's shorter.